# How to improve for loop without getting runtime timeout,

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently working on a project that cross validate 2 sheets with approx 500 loops.

**ROSTER**

| First Name | Last Name | DoB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Judith | Barragan | 4/10/1959 |
| Kelly | Benitez | 9/14/1993 |
| Martha | Bustos | 1/12/1960 |
| Robyn | Carroll | 5/9/1954 |
| Janet | Chambers | 8/27/1949 |
| Nikki | Corso | 10/25/1957 |
| Angella | Decohen | 5/23/1988 |
| Damian | Delaney | 6/26/1961 |
| Anora | Denison | 4/14/1998 |
| Cristina | Dimatulac | 7/28/1959 |
| Mercy | Erazo | 3/14/1959 |
| Michelle | Fanara | 11/20/1981 |
| Shannon | Feldmann | 9/10/1986 |
| Alejandra | Frutos-Silva | 2/14/1978 |
| Rebecka | Aceves | 7/14/2007 |
| Jarely | Aguilera | 6/8/2006 |
| Jasmine | Aguillon | 1/29/2007 |
| Adriana | Alaniz | 10/4/2007 |
| Blanca | Angel | 11/3/2007 |
| Francie | Arellano | 9/11/2007 |
| Molly | Barajas | 10/1/2007 |
| Emily | Barranco | 9/12/2007 |
| Valeria | Bata | 3/29/2007 |
| Sarahi | Cabeza | 8/8/2007 |
| Carla | Cadena | 3/31/2006 |
| Emily | Cano | 1/25/2007 |
| Janet | Canul | 4/27/2007 |
| Caitlyn | Castaneda | 3/26/2007 |
| Jacqueline | Castillo | 1/22/2007 |
| Melanie | Colindres | 6/8/2007 |
| Nyah | Davis | 8/8/2007 |
| Karie | Delgadillo | 2/10/2007 |
| Gabriela | Diaz | 6/25/2007 |
| Helen | Diaz | 8/17/2007 |
| Hailey | Duran | 5/20/2007 |
| Hazel | Flores | 9/7/2007 |
| Kiherra | Gamboa | 10/4/2007 |
| Belen | Gonzalez | 4/23/2007 |
| Samantha | Gonzalez | 10/16/2007 |
| Ashlee | Palacios | 8/31/2006 |
| Naomi | Papaqui | 5/17/2007 |
| Karely | Paxtor | 10/21/2006 |
| Michelle | Paxtor | 10/20/2007 |
| Audra | Perez | 2/24/2007 |
| Josueline | Perez | 10/30/2006 |
| Yaretzi | Pineda | 2/17/2007 |
| Zuleyka | Portela | 9/10/2007 |
| Jacqueline | Prudencio | 3/1/2007 |
| Destiny | Quiroz | 5/10/2007 |
| Kelcey | Raiz | 5/11/2007 |
| Brianna | Ramos | 8/15/2007 |
| Neydy | Renderos | 8/26/2007 |
| Daiman | Johnson | 3/3/1968 |
| Kimberley | Rivas | 11/2/2007 |
| Michelle | Dominguez | 5/15/2005 |
| Marleny | Rodriguez | 7/29/2007 |
| Maria | Roman | 5/9/2006 |
| Cristal | Solis | 9/29/2006 |
| Carmela | Torralba | 6/28/2007 |
| Dora | Vasquez | 5/14/2007 |
| Cindy | Vega | 11/20/2007 |
| Jennifer | Velasco | 6/30/2006 |
| Chloe | Wilson | 10/8/2007 |
| Melody | Zacarias | 5/17/2007 |
| Hazel | Zamora | 1/27/2007 |
| Kayden | Alexander | 2/6/2006 |
| Yvette | Alvarado | 3/30/2006 |
| Damian | Delaney | 6/26/1961 |
| Kimberly | Amezcua | 7/14/2006 |
| Kimberly | Antonio | 5/30/2006 |
| Alicia | Aquino | 6/15/2006 |
| Samantha | Aquino | 6/27/2006 |
| Destiny | Arauz | 6/13/2006 |
| Julissa | Arroyo | 5/26/2006 |
| Cassandra | Ayala | 8/18/2006 |
| Samantha | Ayala | 7/2/2006 |
| Eva | Azul | 2/6/2006 |
| Stacey | Bacelis | 4/4/2006 |
| America | Baires | 7/17/2006 |
| Ashley | Barajas | 6/10/2005 |
| Janet | Barrera | 10/14/2005 |
| Alisa | Benitez | 5/26/2006 |
| Sara | Bolanos-Mejia | 1/12/2006 |
| Ashley | Mendez | 6/22/2006 |
| Ana | Carvente | 7/12/2006 |
| Mia | Castellanos | 6/19/2006 |
| Rosalma | Cebreros | 3/3/2006 |
| Yosselin | Celis | 5/25/2005 |
| Jacqueline | Lucero | 9/2/1974 |
| Evelyn | Chamu | 1/30/2006 |
| Nataly | Chavez | 2/27/2006 |
| Juliana | Coeto | 10/4/2005 |
| Shesith | Covarrubias | 12/8/2005 |
| Ashley | Cruz | 7/20/2006 |
| Erin | Dakers | 8/2/2007 |
| Claudia | Lopez | 6/16/2007 |
| Cristina | Diaz | 10/13/2005 |
| Zoe | Dighero | 4/11/2006 |
| Kaylynn | Domingo | 10/4/2006 |
| Celeste | Dominguez | 6/1/2006 |
| Lizzy | Escobar | 12/14/2005 |
| Lilian | Escorza | 12/23/2005 |

**REGISTRATION**

| First Name | Last Name | DoB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jacqueline | Lucero | 9/2/1974 |
| Ashley | Mendez | 6/22/2006 |
| Hyobe | Namkoong | 6/19/2007 |
| Hetzabel | Sanchez | 4/13/2005 |
| cristal | solis | 9/29/2006 |
| Briseida | Lopez | 5/22/2005 |
| Daiman | Johnson | 3/3/1968 |
| Kayleen | Vasquez | 12/9/2003 |
| Ashley | Aguilar | 12/9/2003 |
| Damian | Delaney | 6/26/1961 |
| Michelle | Dominguez | 5/15/2005 |
| Martha | Bustos | 1/12/1960 |
| Jaqueline | Granadino | 9/6/2004 |
| jacqueline | granadino | 9/6/2004 |
| Jacqueline | granadino | 9/6/2004 |
| Maria | Gutierrez | 11/30/2006 |
| Claudia | Lopez | 6/16/2007 |
| Kelly | Benitez | 9/14/1993 |
| Kelly | Benitez | 9/14/1993 |

**RESULT**

| First Name | Last Name | DoB | Start Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jacqueline | Lucero | 9/2/1974 | 1980001 |
| Ashley | Mendez | 6/22/2006 | 1980002 |
| Cristal | Solis | 9/29/2006 | 1980003 |
| Daiman | Johnson | 3/3/1968 | 1980004 |
| Damian | Delaney | 6/26/1961 | 1980005 |
| Michelle | Dominguez | 5/15/2005 | 1980006 |
| Martha | Bustos | 1/12/1960 | 1980007 |
| Claudia | Lopez | 6/16/2007 | 1980008 |
| Kelly | Benitez | 9/14/1993 | 1980009 |

[Sample Data Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17dZhD1XCnt_oXbRvSC1guYdBAMGpiQDUWwIDwZ1FLcI/edit?usp=sharing)
my problem is that my script sometimes getting run-time timeout. I am seeing map function but I'm not sure if it's applicable for my current problem.

here are my sheets that is included in my script.
sheets are roster, form responses 1, reference, result.
roster and registration tab have common columns (First name, Last Name, Date of Birth)

```
var SS              = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var rosterTab       = SS.getSheetByName('Roster')
var registrationTab = SS.getSheetByName('Responses 1')
var referenceTab    = SS.getSheetByName('Reference')
var resultTab       = SS.getSheetByName('Result') //this is where I posts all registered names that is on the roster tab.
var xLastRow        = registrationTab.getLastRow();
var yLastRow        = rosterTab.getLastRow();
var Data            = [];
var codeStart       = referenceTab.getRange('A1').getValue();
var rosterdata      = rosterTab.getRange(1,1,300,3).getValues();
var registerdata    = registrationTab.getRange(1,1,xLastRow,3).getValues();

for(var i = 0; i<yLastRow; i++(){
    for(var j = 0; j<xLastRow; j++(){
        if (rosterdata[i][0] === registerdata[j][0] && rosterdata[i][1] === registerdata[j][1] && rosterdata[i][2] === registerdata[j][2]){
            var rosterFname = registerdata[j][0];
            var rosterLname = registerdata[j][1];
            var rosterDoB   = registerdata[j][2];
            var rosterCode  = codeStart;

            Data.push([rosterFname,rosterLname,rosterDoB,rosterCode]);

            break;
        }
    }
}
resultTab.getRange( resultTab.getLastRow()+1, 1, Data.length,Data[0].length ).setValues(Data);
```

Is there another way on how to approach this matching without getting timed-out?

Comment: I think that your script is incomplete when I saw `for(var i = 0; i<yLastRow; i++(){` and `for(var j = 0; j<xLastRow; j++(){`. So, I'm worried that your actual script might be different from your showing script. And also, in your question, 3 sheets like "ROSTER", "REGISTRATION" and "RESULT" are used. In your script, 4 sheets of "Roster", "Responses 1", "Reference" and "Result" are used. And, when I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I cannot find the sheet "Responses 1" and "REGISTRATION". So I cannot understand your question. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. The goal for this script is to check incoming registrants from "Registration form Responses" with "Roster". the Roster sheet is already populated from the school. If the registrant is found in Roster it will be posted in the Result with Code# found in "Reference" sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot still understand your question. I cannot understand the relationship between your sample data in your question and your sample Spreadsheet. Can I ask you about this?

Comment: @Tanaike I'm actually looking for a solution if there's a much more efficient way or a faster function to do it. my current script structure is giving runtime timeout because it loops 500-600 loops per name in the response.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike If you open the sample spreadsheet, I added a tab for you, I also added a flow chart there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239969/discussion-between-jantzen-bautista-and-tanaike).

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Cooper Reversed duplicate. Reasons: This has more answers, accepted answer and the answer present there is also present here. Therefore, This seems a better target than the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myfunky11() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const rosterTab = ss.getSheetByName('Roster');
  const registrationTab = ss.getSheetByName('Responses 1');
  const referenceTab = ss.getSheetByName('Reference');
  let rsh = ss.getSheetByName('Result'); 
  var data = [];
  const codeStart = referenceTab.getRange('A1').getValue();
  const ros = rosterTab.getRange(2, 1, rosterTab.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getDisplayValues().map(r => r[0] + r[1] + r[2]);
  const reg = registrationTab.getRange(2, 1, registrationTab.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  reg.forEach(r => {
    let s = r[0].toString() + r[1].toString() + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(r[2]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/yyyy");
    if (ros.indexOf(s)>-1) {
      r.push(codeStart);
      data.push(r)
    }
  });
  rsh.clear();
  rsh.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

This works now

Answer (score 1):

You could process all the "Roster" data in batches by keeping track of the last row that you have processed with [`PropertiesService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

```
const LAST_PROCESSED_ROW_PROPERTY_KEY = 'lastProcessedRow';
const PROCESS_ROW_PER_BATCH           = 100;

var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var lastProcessedRow = scriptProperties.getProperty( LAST_PROCESSED_ROW_PROPERTY_KEY );

if ( lastProcessedRow === null ) {
    lastProcessedRow = 0;
}

// Your variables here

var yLastRow          = rosterTab.getLastRow();
var rowsToBeProcessed = PROCESS_ROW_PER_BATCH;

if ( lastProcessedRow == yLastRow ) {
    Logger.log( 'No new data to be processed' );

    return;
}

if ( yLastRow - lastProcessedRow < PROCESS_ROW_PER_BATCH ) {
    rowsToBeProcessed = yLastRow - lastProcessedRow;
}

var rosterdata = rosterTab.getRange( lastProcessedRow + 1, 1, rowsToBeProcessed, 3 ).getValues();

for( var i = 0; i < rosterdata.length; i++ ) {
    // Your data processing logic here
}

// Set data logic here

scriptProperties.setProperty( LAST_PROCESSED_ROW_PROPERTY_KEY, lastProcessedRow + rowsToBeProcessed );
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- There are 3 sheets in your Spreadsheet.
- You want to retrieve the values from "Form Response 1" and "Roster" sheets. When the values from the columns "B" to "D" in "Form Response 1" sheet are the same as the columns "A" to "C" in "Roster" sheet, you want to put them to "Result" sheet as the append values.
- You want to reduce the process cost of this process.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rosterTab = SS.getSheetByName('Roster');
  var registrationTab = SS.getSheetByName('Form Response 1');
  var referenceTab = SS.getSheetByName('Reference');
  var resultTab = SS.getSheetByName('Result');
  var xLastRow = registrationTab.getLastRow();
  var yLastRow = rosterTab.getLastRow();
  var Data = [];
  var codeStart = referenceTab.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var rosterdata = rosterTab.getRange(1, 1, yLastRow, 3).getValues();
  var registerdata = registrationTab.getRange(2, 2, xLastRow - 1, 3).getValues();

  // I modified below script.
  // Create an object.
  var obj = rosterdata.reduce((o, [a,b,c]) => (o[a + b + c] = true, o), {});

  // Create an array for putting to sheet.
  var values = registerdata.reduce((ar, [a, b, c]) => {
    if (obj[a + b + c]) ar.push([a, b, c, codeStart]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  
  // Put the array to the result sheet.
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  resultTab.getRange(resultTab.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- In this modification, create an object for searching the values and create an array for putting to the sheet, and the created array is appended to the result sheet. By this flow, I thought that the process cost might be able to be reduced a little.

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)